# Make the character smaller than others and at the bottom right in NSString iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, fonts, nsstring

I want to make the string as [image: 100%]

I used this code but it always show the '%' at the top right.

```
UIFont *PercentFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"System" size:30];

NSString* percentString =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%%",value ];

NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:percentString attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: PercentFont}];

[attributedString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor colorWithRed:240/255.0 green:133/255.0 blue:105/255.0 alpha:1.0] range:NSMakeRange(0, percentString.length -1)];

[attributedString setAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"System" size:17]  ,NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName : @17} range:NSMakeRange(percentString.length -1, 1)];


 // set % digit color
[attributedString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor colorWithRed:240/255.0 green:133/255.0 blue:105/255.0 alpha:1.0] range:NSMakeRange(percentString.length -1, 1)];
```

Please help to correct it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code for this:

```
UIFont *PercentFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:30];

NSString* percentString =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%%",9];

NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:percentString attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: PercentFont}];

[attributedString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor colorWithRed:240/255.0 green:133/255.0 blue:105/255.0 alpha:1.0] range:NSMakeRange(0, percentString.length -1)];

[attributedString setAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17]  ,NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName : @-2} range:NSMakeRange(percentString.length -1, 1)];


// set % digit color
[attributedString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor colorWithRed:240/255.0 green:133/255.0 blue:105/255.0 alpha:1.0] range:NSMakeRange(percentString.length -1, 1)];
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(120, 100, 200, 100)];
label.attributedText =attributedString;
```

It will be good idea change PercentFont by percentFont (lower case).